# How to ignore words in string using Regular Expressions

Tags: c#, regex

I need a piece of regex that can be used to do a NOT match.  Take for example the following URL's

```
 http://www.site.com/layout/default.aspx
 http://www.site.com/default.aspx
 http://www.site.com/layout.aspx
```

The regex should NOT match any url string that contains the directory "layout"

```
http://www.site.com/layout/default.aspx
```

and instead should match on

```
http://www.site.com/default.aspx
http://www.site.com/layout.aspx
```

How can i do this using .NET regex?

Comment: Depends on what tool you are using.

Comment: As per my answer, it can be done with negative lookahead, which is supported in most regex implementations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use negative lookahead:

`^(?!.*/layout/)`

You have to anchor to the start of the string or you'll get false positives i.e. `(?!/layout/)` alone won't work.

Comment: Thanks, this kinda worked.  I eneded using 'h t t p://domain/(?!.*layout/).+' as i need to return the matches.

Comment: Glad I could help. If you want to make it a little cleaner, you could use this: `(?!.*/layout/)http://domain/.+`

Answer (score 1):

If you need to squeeze everything in one regex, try negative lookahead, something along the lines of this:

`(?!layout)`

Comment: This won't work, because it will match the first location in the string that isn't followed by "layout".

Comment: @Bennor McCarthy: Yes, combine this with the real regex for the url and it will work. Something like this (rough, untested, not fully thought-through example, so beware): `http://[-a-z0-9]+.com/((?!layout).+/)*[^.]+\..+` PLEASE don't ever use this regex for real, it makes a LOT of faulty assumptions (like every file has the format name.extension).

Comment: Yeah, fair enough, but you'd still be tying it to an exact location in the string (which may be okay, depending on the requirements).

Answer (score 0):

Just match `/layout/` and invert the result, whatever language you use.

E.g. with PHP:

```
if(!preg_match('#/layout/#i', $url)) {
    // does not match layout
}
```

Answer (score 0):

PYTHON:

```
import re
if not re.match('layout'):
      #do whatever here
```

re is regex for python