# Ignore String containing special words (Months)

Tags: c++, regex, string

I am trying to find alphanumeric strings by using the following regular expression:

```
^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-zA-Z]).{3,90}$
```

---

**Alphanumeric string:** an alphanumeric string is any string that contains at least a number and a letter plus **any** other special characters it can be @ - _ [] () {} ç _ \ ù %

---

I want to add an extra constraint to ignore all alphanumerical strings containing the following month formats :

```
JANVIER|FEVRIER|MARS|AVRIL|MAI|JUIN|JUILLET|AOUT|SEPTEMBRE|OCTOBRE|NOVEMBRE|DECEMBRE|Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|JUN|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec|[jJ]anvier|[fF][ée]vrier|[mM]ars|[aA]vril|[mM]ai|[jJ]uin|[jJ]uillet|[aA]o[éû]t|aout|[sS]eptembre|[oO]ctobre|[nN]ovembre|[dD][eé]cembre
```

---

One solution is to actually match an alphanumerical string. Then check if this string contains one of these names by using the following function:

```
 vector<string> findString(string s)
    {
        vector<string> vec;
        boost::regex rgx("JANVIER|FEVRIER|MARS|AVRIL|MAI|JUIN|JUILLET|AOUT|SEPTEMBRE|OCTOBRE|NOVEMBRE|DECEMBRE|Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|JUN|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec|[jJ]anvier|[fF][ée]vrier|[mM]ars|[aA]vril|[mM]ai|[jJ]uin|[jJ]uillet|[aA]o[éû]t|aout|[sS]eptembre|[oO]ctobre|[nN]ovembre|[dD][eé]cembre
");
        boost::smatch match;

        boost::sregex_iterator begin {s.begin(), s.end(), rgx},
              end {};

        for (boost::sregex_iterator& i = begin; i != end; ++i)
        {
            boost::smatch m = *i;
            vec.push_back(m.str());
        }

        return vec;
    }
```

---

Question: How can I add this constraint directly into the regular expression instead of using this function.

One solution is to use  negative lookahead as mentioned in [How to ignore words in string using Regular Expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4643324/how-to-ignore-words-in-string-using-regular-expressions).

---

**I used it as follows:**

String : 2-hello-001

Regular expression : `^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-zA-Z]^(?!Jan|Feb|Mar)).{3,90}$`

Result: no match

Test website: http://regexlib.com/

---

The edit provided by @Robin and @RyanCarlson : `^[][\w@_(){}ç\\ù%-]{3,90}$` works perfectly in detecting alphanumeric strings with special characters. It's just the negative lookahead part that isn't working.

Comment: Why do you need `^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-zA-Z]).{3,90}$`? Wouldn't something like `^[a-zA-Z0-9]{3,90}$` be better?

Comment: Well With your suggestion @RyanCarlson if I want for example to match the following string : **555_tdstg--hani** i can't do it.

Comment: Your current regex will match _any_ string that has at least one digit and one alphabetic letter.

Comment: yes that's what I want actually @RyanCarlson I want to match alphanumeric strings. What do you think is wrong?

Comment: It will also match strings like `a1"&@^&@?<.?\]\[~`@^@^`

Comment: Well I want my regular expression to match: Alphanumeric strings + Special characters. Sorry I wasn't clear

Comment: Please define (by updating your question, so it'll be clear for everyone) what special characters you want to match.

Comment: Do you want whitespace as well? And `/`? You should use code markup for these characters, I edited your question to try and clarify that.

Comment: @Robin Yes I do need these characters. But I mean for now it's not a big issue for me. It's just how I can excluse these strings contains the month names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use negative look ahead, the same way you're using positive lookahead:

```
(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-zA-Z])
(?!.*(?:JANVIER|FEVRIER|MARS|AVRIL|MAI|JUIN|JUILLET|AOUT|SEPTEMBRE|OCTOBRE|NOVEMBRE|DECEMBRE|Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|JUN|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec|[jJ]anvier|[fF][ée]vrier|[mM]ars|[aA]vril|[mM]ai|[jJ]uin|[jJ]uillet|[aA]o[éû]t|aout|[sS]eptembre|[oO]ctobre|[nN]ovembre|[dD][eé]cembre)).{3,90}$
```

Also you regex is pretty unclear. If you want alphanumerical strings with a length between 3 and 90, you can just do:

```
/^(?!.*(?:JANVIER|F[Eé]VRIER|MARS|AVRIL|MAI|JUIN|JUILLET|AO[Uù]T|SEPTEMBRE|OCTOBRE|NOVEMBRE|D[Eé]CEMBRE|Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec))
[][\w@_(){}ç\\ù%-]{3,90}$/i
```

the `i` flag means it will match upper and lower case (so you can reduce your forbidden list), `\w` is a shortcut for `[0-9a-zA-Z_]` (careful if you copy-paste, there's a linebreak here for readability between `(?! )` and `[ ]`). Just add in the final `[...]` whatever special characters you wanna match.

Comment: YEs i did use the negative lookahead @Robin

Comment: @Robin `\w` also matches `_`.

Comment: @Robin I am trying to use the one that u posted Robin but it's not working. Please try it on the following website: http://tinyurl.com/n4bhlxw

Comment: http://goo.gl/ZbqCFX Also, what characters do you mean by alphanumerical? You seem to include `-`.

Comment: yes Well alphanumeric string + **special characters** special characters = "-_$\"

Comment: @Hani Goc: This was not clear in your question. If these are the only special characters you need, see the updated answer. If there may be more (like punctuation, characters with accents, spaces...), either add these characters or use `[^ ]` to match anything but these few characters. Also thx, @Ryan.

Comment: Ahh ok ok yes It wasn't clear @RyanCarlson I am sorry. I'll follow the steps that u gave me

Comment: Updated answer again, just update the final `[ ]` to match what you want and you should be good.

Comment: @Robin I am having a problem These regular expression isn't working. I did try it many times: http://tinyurl.com/lffnocu

Comment: ok Now **^[][\w@_(){}ç\\ù%-]{3,90}$** works perfectly it's just the negative lookahead part that isn't working

Comment: http://goo.gl/i2uS17 Works fine for me (your links just take be to a homepage, I don't see anything you may have typed there :/). There's a linebreak in the code I posted on stackoverflow for readability between the negative lookahead and the matching, did you remove it? May not be obvious indeed.

Comment: @Robin the link that you posted now has the right regular expression

Comment: Is the **/i** unique for a language? because on boost it isn't working

Comment: One Question @Robin How can I force it to contain at least 1 numeric??

Comment: 1) For at least one number: `(?=.*\d)` (for alphanum `(?=[a-z0-9])`) at the beginning of the regex. 2) `i` flag is regex language, but maybe you need to pass flags another way than `/regex/flags`. Some regex flavor support `(?i)` at the beginning of the regex, some functions take regex and flags as two different parameters. You should see the doc of the function you're using your regex in.